# Retrieve the last 5 comment URLs

Tags: comments

I want to retrieve the comment url of last 5 comments.

Is it Possible and how?

when using `get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID)` it returns current page url

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, the last 5 comments on anything:

```
$comments = get_comments( array( 'count' => 5 ) );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo get_comment_link( $comment );
}
```

For a specific post or page comments, just change the $comments line to:

```
$comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => 1, 'count' => 5 ) ); // where the value of post_id is the ID of whatever post or page you want to retrieve comments from
```